# Editing functions in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to edit an inherited function `name()`, and ensure that the inherited function `info()` will call `child::name()` rather than `parent::name()` when called by an instance of `child`.

```
class parent {
public:
    string name() { return "parent"; }

    void info() {
        cout << "This class is " << name() << endl;
    }
};

class child : public parent {
public:
    string name() { return "child"; }
};

int main() {
    parent p;
    child c;
    p.info(); // outputs "parent"
    c.info(); // outputs "parent" - I want "child"
}
```

How can I get `c.info()` to use `child::name()`? I will never need `name()` outside of `info()`, and I don't really want to duplicate `info()` in the child class, as I am trying to avoid repeating a rather long block of code in my real problem.

Comment: `parent::name()` needs to be marked `virtual` and `child::name()` should be marked `override`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You have declared a non polymorphic function

If a member function `f()` of your parent is not `virtual`, it is not polymorphic.  So if this function is called by another function of the parent,  it is `parent::f()` that will be called.

If this function is hidden by another function `f()` in the child, with exactly the same signature,  and if this function is called by another function of the child,  it is `child::f()` that will be called.

Interestingly, if you invoke the function directly for an object, the function of the declared type of the object will be invoked.

### Polymorphic functions

If you want to make your function polymorphic, you have to define it as `virtual` in the parent.  Suppose it is overriden in the child.  In this case,  when you call `f()`, it will always be the `f()` defined for the real type of the object.

```
class parent {
public:
    virtual string name() { return "parent"; }

    ...
    }
};

class child : public parent {
public:
    string name() override { return "child"; }
};
```

With this programm, you'll get this result:

```
This class is parent
This class is child
```

Comment: This one deserves more than a single upvote, I didn't even know that keywords or what polymorphism was and I found all my questions answered in a single post. Thanks +1

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Thank you for this positive feedback! I’m very happy to read that it was helpful.